# Connecting multiple devices via I2C

Tags: gpio, i2c

http://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/breakout-boards/adafruit/adafruit-pwmservo-driver-16-channel-12-bit-pca9685

How do I connect two I2C devices to my R Pi? Specificaly 16 Channel 12 Bit PWM Servo Motor Driver and LED Controller-PCA9685 and Gyroscope?

Comment: normally there is a set of pins dedicated to changing the address of the device. You may need to solder or desolder a pair of pads or tie them to high or low. Based on the description from the link above there are 6 address pins.

Answer (score 7):

I2C is a bus.  You can connect multiple devices to a bus.

I2C requires that each device on the bus has a unique address (generally a small number between 0 and 127).  Manufactures tend to give different types of device different addresses, so normally there is no need to do anything special.

As far as wiring is concerned just connect each device to SDA and SCL (and power and ground).  The SDA and SCL signals can be shared between devices, just like power and ground can be shared.

Answer (score -4):

You need multiple I2C Buses for that, which you need to configure on your Pi properly. [Here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/) is a guide!